# How to place protected routes within an array in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, routes, navigation

I'm hoping to set up protected routes for my webapp built with React.js. I have an array 'menuOptions' that I have been looping through to add options to my navbar. However, I've now been running in to issues as I would like to add protected routes.

So for instance, I would like to have Home, Login and Register when the user is logged out, and Dashboard and Logout as the options for when the user is logged in. I'd really appreciate any help. Ideally, I'd somehow add the '!user' to the menuOptions array somehow.

My code is below (as you can see menuOptions does not do anything for the above at the moment):

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Link, NavLink, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth, logout } from "../../firebase";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  appbar: {
    // background: 'none',
  },
  inactiveLink: {
    color: "white",
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    fontSize: "1.5rem",
  },
  activeLink: {
    color: "black",
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    fontSize: "1.5rem",
    background: "#bfbfbf",
  },
}));

function Navigation() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const menuOptions = [
    { label: "Home", path: "/",  },
    { label: "Register", path: "/register" },
    { label: "Dashboard", path: "/dashboard" },
    { label: "Logout", path: "/logout" },
  ];

  const handleMenuSelect = (pageURL) => {
    navigate(pageURL);
  };

  const handleMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <>
      <AppBar
        className={classes.appbar}
        position="fixed"
        elevation={0}
        color="primary"
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.title}>
            The Football App
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            All you ever wanted to know about Football!
          </Typography>
          {isMobile ? (
            <>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="menu"
                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleMenu}
                color="inherit"
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                keepMounted
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: "top",
                  horizontal: "right",
                }}
                open={open}
                onClose={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
              >
                {menuOptions.map((opt) => (
                  <MenuItem
                    key={opt.label}
                    onClick={() => handleMenuSelect(opt.path)}
                  >
                    {opt.label}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Menu>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <nav>
                <div>
                  {!user ? (
                    <NavLink
                      to="/"
                      className={({ isActive }) =>
                        isActive
                      }
                    >
                      Home
                    </NavLink>
                  ) : (
                    <NavLink
                      to="/dashboard"
                      className={({ isActive }) =>
                        isActive
                      }
                    >
                      Dashboard
                    </NavLink>
                  )}
                </div>
                {!user ? (
                  <div>
                    <Link to="/login">
                      <a>Login</a>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/register">
                      <a>Register</a>
                    </Link>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                  <div className="navbar-end">
                    <Link to="/logout">
                      <a>Log Out</a>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                )}
              </nav>
            </>
          )}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your `menuOptions` object to include a `protected` key:

```js
const menuOptions = [
    { label: "Home", path: "/", protected:  false },
    { label: "Register", path: "/register", protected:  false },
    { label: "Dashboard", path: "/dashboard", protected:  false },
    { label: "Logout", path: "/logout", protected:  true },
  ];
```

and update the logic where your render your menu options to something like

```js
{menuOptions.map((opt) => {
  if (opt.protected && !user) return;
  return (
    <MenuItem
      key={opt.label}
      onClick={() => handleMenuSelect(opt.path)}
    >
      {opt.label}
    </MenuItem>
  );
}
)}
```

to only show certain options if the user exists

```js
{menuOptions.filter((opt) => (user ? opt.protected : !opt.protected)).map((opt) =>  (
    <MenuItem
      key={opt.label}
      onClick={() => handleMenuSelect(opt.path)}
    >
      {opt.label}
    </MenuItem>
  )
)}
```

Comment: Hi, this worked really nicely. Thank you so much for your response. The only thing that is still a little off is that when I am now logged in, I can still see the 'false' menu options. Is it possible to hide these when logged in? The 'true' menu options are hidden when I am logged out, but the 'false' menu options still appear when I'm logged in unfortunately @adam_th

Comment: You can just change the logic in the menu options block to filter the options you want to render in that case. I'll update the original answer with an example